# Changing the site URL

Tags: domain, site-url, home-url, ip

## Overview:

I have a self-hosted WordPress installation *currently* without a domain.

Example: http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx/~someaccountname

In a few days a domain will be pointing to this installation and I'll need to update the site URL. I'm not migrating. I'm simply changing the home/site URL from an IP-based URL to a domain-based URL.

[I've already read through the codex on the matter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) but apart from changing the Home URL and Site URL under General Settings, the codex appears to be outlining fixes rather than any other steps additional to changing the URLs via General Settings.

## Questions:

1. In your experience, is it a straight forward process
   changing from an IP-based site URL to domain-based site URL? Is it a problematic affair that should be avoided by creating a fresh hosting account entirely?
2. Is anyone aware of potential problems this could create with plugins such as WooCommerce?

Note: [I have reviewed existing questions/answers on this website.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=Changing+the+site+URL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to phpmyadmin the best way in my opinion is to get [WP migrate Db](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) Plugin, then create an export sql file with new url address and upload it with PhpmyAdmin.

That way you ensure that every place in the site with old url get replaced with new url in a **safe way** (you can't do a simple search and replace because it won't work)

Regarding your 2 questions:
1 With this plugin is pretty straight forward. Create a database backup just in case, but you shouldn't have problems
2 No problem if is replaced this way.

Comment: I backed-up using the standard WordPress export, the theme and framework export for WooCommerce and finally the core database files using the WP-DB-Backup plugin. I then used the WP Migrate DB plugin as instructed but I've received the following error: Warning: Missing argument 1 for WC_Shipping_Rate.

Comment: I ignored the error message and proceeded with the import. I encountered an additional server related error with regards to to readfile() not being allowed which in the simplest of terms meant that I couldn't download the outputted file to machine and instead had to output it on a location on my server and thereafter downloaded it. Once downloaded, the import into phpMyAdmin was swift and testing went without a hitch. Thanks for a great solution and for recommending an equally great plugin that automated my work-flow.