# How to change all the urls of the WordPress site?

Tags: plugins, php, functions, urls

We have created an online store with WordPress on a domain and now that we have finished testing, we must take it to the final domain.

I only need a method to change all the URLs of the site
I have seen options on this site in one of the questions that this one [was made 4 years ago](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/313424/change-old-urls-after-the-domain-change), or [this one 5 years ago](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/274899/cant-change-the-wordpress-site-url),
maybe they are old, it is possible that there is a more effective way.
[I have even seen some question from 2013](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121757/changing-the-site-url)

The option to export the SQL file might be nice, but maybe you can make a mistake and leave something unchanged.

I have read about the "guid" field but I don't understand what we need to do in this regard
What is the best way to change the URLs of the site after changing the domain?

Is there a function to achieve this ? Should I use a plugin?

I am willing to do it manually if necessary, if there is documentation that can guide me

Thanks

Comment: The old question you link to contains a description of the plugin you need.

Comment: Which one of them ? All questions are older than 4 years, so I have doubts about its effectiveness and ask the question

Comment: The process for this hasn’t changed in the last 4 years, but I would refer you to the official documentation: https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/moving-wordpress/

Comment: Thank you. I managed to make the change by reading this documentation carefully. Can you write an answer to show that my question had a solution and can be useful for other users? Should I write a solution? Thanks